# Php Two Table Update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL database that looks similar to this:

COUPON TABLE

```
| id | coupon_id | host      | away        |guess    |skor  |status|
+----+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------+
|  1 | 22        | Barcelona | Real Madrid | 1       |2-1   | 1    |
|  2 | 22        | Celtic    | Porto       | 2       |1-0   | 2    |
|  3 | 23        | Barcelona | Real Madrid | 1       |2-1   | 1    |
|  4 | 23        | M city   | Chelsea      | 1       |4-1    | 1   |
```

COUPONS TABLE

```
| id | user       | Copuonstatus
+----+------------+-------------+
|  22 | Admin     | 0           | 
|  23 | Roberto   | 0           |
```

I need to sort the results in a table that looks like this:

```
COUPONS TABLE

| id | user       | Copuonstatus
+----+------------+-------------+
|  22 | Admin     | 2           | 
|  23 | Roberto   | 1           | 


NOTE : 
Copuonstatus= default value 0
status = 0 waiting
status = 1 win
status = 2 los
```

im query try, 
I could not
or update INNER JOIN use?

```
$q=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupons INNER JOIN coupon ON 
coupon.coupon_id = coupons.id AND coupon.status=2");
$q->execute();
$sss=$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
if ( $sss > 0){ 
$db->exec("UPDATE coupons SET coupon_status = 2  FROM coupons ON 
coupon.coupon_id = coupons.id WHERE coupons.Copuonstatus=0 ");}
```

Comment: I think you'd want something like this `UPDATE coupons as cs
join coupon as c
on c.coupon_id = cs.id
SET c.coupon_status = 2 
WHERE cs.Copuonstatus = 0` but i don't really know if there are other issues with your code.. for example how does `$sss` come into play?

Comment: i couldn't do the query right :( 
in this regard help

Comment: In that case see comment 2 (deleting first comment). If that fails please provide error code, if it updates the wrong data please explain how it should have worked.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Please provide the data after the `If that fails` part of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
  coupons AS A
  INNER JOIN coupon AS B ON A.id = B.coupon_id
SET
  coupon_status = 2
WHERE
  A.Copuonstatus = 0
```

Hope it help